# Win32 API C++, Identifier not Received with WM_COMMAND

Tags: c++, winapi, menuitem, identifier, wm-command

I'm a fairly new Win32 API C++ programmer.

I've just learned how to create menus and attach them Window instances.
The trouble I'm having is, my MenuItem Identifiers don't seem to be sending.

For Example:
My menu item File>>Exit is supposed to send the Identifier ID_FILE_EXIT in WM_COMMAND.
But somewhere along the line, my MSG switch isn't receiving that identifier; ie my menu items don't work.

resouce.h:

```
// resources.h

#ifndef RESOURCE_H
#define RESOURCE_H

// Main Window: Menu ID
#define IDR_MAIN_MENU          101

// Main Window: Menu: Command IDs
#define ID_FILE_EXIT           101101

#define ID_PRIMITIVE_LINE      101201
#define ID_PRIMITIVE_RECTANGLE 101202
#define ID_PRIMITIVE_ELLIPSE   101203

#define ID_PENCOLOUR_BLACK     101301
#define ID_PENCOLOUR_WHITE     101302
#define ID_PENCOLOUR_RED       101303
#define ID_PENCOLOUR_GREEN     101304
#define ID_PENCOLOUR_BLUE      101305

#define ID_BRUSHCOLOUR_BLACK   101401
#define ID_BRUSHCOLOUR_WHITE   101402
#define ID_BRUSHCOLOUR_RED     101403
#define ID_BRUSHCOLOUR_GREEN   101404
#define ID_BRUSHCOLOUR_BLUE    101405

#define ID_PENSTYLE_SOLID      101501
#define ID_PENSTYLE_NULL       101502
#define ID_PENSTYLE_DOTTED     101503
#define ID_PENSTYLE_DASHED     101504

#define ID_BRUSHSTYLE_SOLID    101601
#define ID_BRUSHSTYLE_NULL     101602
#define ID_BRUSHSTYLE_DIAGONAL 101603
#define ID_BRUSHSTYLE_CROSS    101604

#endif // RESOURCE_H
```

resource.rc:

```
// resouce.rc

#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
#include <richedit.h>
#include "resource.h"

IDR_MAIN_MENU MENU
{
    popup "File"
    {
        MENUITEM "Exit",        ID_FILE_EXIT
    }

    popup "Primitive"
    {
        MENUITEM "Line",        ID_PRIMITIVE_LINE
        MENUITEM "Rectangle",   ID_PRIMITIVE_RECTANGLE
        MENUITEM "Ellipse",     ID_PRIMITIVE_ELLIPSE
    }

    popup "Pen Colour"
    {
        MENUITEM "Black",       ID_PENCOLOUR_BLACK
        MENUITEM "White",       ID_PENCOLOUR_WHITE
        MENUITEM "Red",         ID_PENCOLOUR_RED
        MENUITEM "Green",       ID_PENCOLOUR_GREEN
        MENUITEM "Blue",        ID_PENCOLOUR_BLUE
    }

    popup "Brush Colour"
    {
        MENUITEM "Black",       ID_BRUSHCOLOUR_BLACK
        MENUITEM "White",       ID_BRUSHCOLOUR_WHITE
        MENUITEM "Red",         ID_BRUSHCOLOUR_RED
        MENUITEM "Green",       ID_BRUSHCOLOUR_GREEN
        MENUITEM "Blue",        ID_BRUSHCOLOUR_BLUE
    }

    popup "PenStyle"
    {
        MENUITEM "Solid",       ID_PENSTYLE_SOLID
        MENUITEM "Dotted",      ID_PENSTYLE_DOTTED
        MENUITEM "Dashed",      ID_PENSTYLE_DASHED
    }

    popup "Brush Style"
    {
        MENUITEM "Solid",       ID_BRUSHSTYLE_SOLID
        MENUITEM "Null",        ID_BRUSHSTYLE_NULL
        MENUITEM "Diagonal",    ID_BRUSHSTYLE_DIAGONAL
        MENUITEM "Cross",       ID_BRUSHSTYLE_CROSS
    }
}
```

main.cpp(extract) - msg switch statement:

```
...

switch(msg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        CheckMenuItem(ghMainMenu, ID_PRIMITIVE_LINE, MF_CHECKED);
        CheckMenuItem(ghMainMenu, ID_PENCOLOUR_BLACK, MF_CHECKED);
        CheckMenuItem(ghMainMenu, ID_BRUSHCOLOUR_BLACK, MF_CHECKED);
        CheckMenuItem(ghMainMenu, ID_PENSTYLE_SOLID, MF_CHECKED);
        CheckMenuItem(ghMainMenu, ID_BRUSHSTYLE_SOLID, MF_CHECKED);
        return 0;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch(LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        //=====================================
        // File Menu
        //=====================================
        case ID_FILE_EXIT:
            DestroyWindow(ghMainWnd);
            return 0;

        //=====================================
        // Primitive Types (Shape Types)
        //=====================================
        case ID_PRIMITIVE_LINE:
            CheckMenuItem(ghMainMenu, ID_PRIMITIVE_LINE, MF_CHECKED);
            CheckMenuItem(ghMainMenu, gCurrPrimSel, MF_UNCHECKED);
            gCurrPrimSel = ID_PRIMITIVE_LINE;
            return 0;

        case ID_PRIMITIVE_RECTANGLE:
            CheckMenuItem(ghMainMenu, ID_PRIMITIVE_RECTANGLE, MF_CHECKED);
            CheckMenuItem(ghMainMenu, gCurrPrimSel, MF_UNCHECKED);
            gCurrPrimSel = ID_PRIMITIVE_RECTANGLE;
            return 0;

        case ID_PRIMITIVE_ELLIPSE:
            CheckMenuItem(ghMainMenu, ID_PRIMITIVE_ELLIPSE, MF_CHECKED);
            CheckMenuItem(ghMainMenu, gCurrPrimSel, MF_UNCHECKED);
            gCurrPrimSel = ID_PRIMITIVE_ELLIPSE;
            return 0;

        //=====================================
        // Pen Colours
        //=====================================
        case ID_PENCOLOUR_BLACK:
            CheckMenuItem(ghMainMenu, ID_PENCOLOUR_BLACK, MF_CHECKED);
            CheckMenuItem(ghMainMenu, gCurrPenColSel, MF_UNCHECKED);
            gCurrPenColSel    = ID_PENCOLOUR_BLACK;
            gLogPen.lopnColor = BLACK;
            return 0;

        case ID_PENCOLOUR_WHITE:
            CheckMenuItem(ghMainMenu, ID_PENCOLOUR_WHITE, MF_CHECKED);
            CheckMenuItem(ghMainMenu, gCurrPenColSel, MF_UNCHECKED);
            gCurrPenColSel    = ID_PENCOLOUR_WHITE;
            gLogPen.lopnColor = BLACK;
            return 0;

        case ID_PENCOLOUR_RED:
            CheckMenuItem(ghMainMenu, ID_PENCOLOUR_RED, MF_CHECKED);
            CheckMenuItem(ghMainMenu, gCurrPenColSel, MF_UNCHECKED);
            gCurrPenColSel    = ID_PENCOLOUR_RED;
            gLogPen.lopnColor = BLACK;
            return 0;

        case ID_PENCOLOUR_GREEN:
            CheckMenuItem(ghMainMenu, ID_PENCOLOUR_GREEN, MF_CHECKED);
            CheckMenuItem(ghMainMenu, gCurrPenColSel, MF_UNCHECKED);
            gCurrPenColSel    = ID_PENCOLOUR_GREEN;
            gLogPen.lopnColor = GREEN;
            return 0;

        case ID_PENCOLOUR_BLUE:
            CheckMenuItem(ghMainMenu, ID_PENCOLOUR_BLUE, MF_CHECKED);
            CheckMenuItem(ghMainMenu, gCurrPenColSel, MF_UNCHECKED);
            gCurrPenColSel    = ID_PENCOLOUR_BLUE;
            gLogPen.lopnColor = BLUE;
            return 0;

        //=====================================
        // Brush Colours
        //=====================================
        case ID_BRUSHCOLOUR_BLACK:
            CheckMenuItem(ghMainMenu, ID_BRUSHCOLOUR_BLACK, MF_CHECKED);
            CheckMenuItem(ghMainMenu, gCurrBrushColSel, MF_UNCHECKED);
            gCurrBrushColSel  = ID_BRUSHCOLOUR_BLACK;
            gLogBrush.lbColor = BLACK;
            return 0;

        case ID_BRUSHCOLOUR_WHITE:
            CheckMenuItem(ghMainMenu, ID_BRUSHCOLOUR_WHITE, MF_CHECKED);
            CheckMenuItem(ghMainMenu, gCurrBrushColSel, MF_UNCHECKED);
            gCurrBrushColSel  = ID_BRUSHCOLOUR_WHITE;
            gLogBrush.lbColor = WHITE;
            return 0;

        case ID_BRUSHCOLOUR_RED:
            CheckMenuItem(ghMainMenu, ID_BRUSHCOLOUR_RED, MF_CHECKED);
            CheckMenuItem(ghMainMenu, gCurrBrushColSel, MF_UNCHECKED);
            gCurrBrushColSel  = ID_BRUSHCOLOUR_RED;
            gLogBrush.lbColor = RED;
            return 0;

        case ID_BRUSHCOLOUR_GREEN:
            CheckMenuItem(ghMainMenu, ID_BRUSHCOLOUR_GREEN, MF_CHECKED);
            CheckMenuItem(ghMainMenu, gCurrBrushColSel, MF_UNCHECKED);
            gCurrBrushColSel  = ID_BRUSHCOLOUR_GREEN;
            gLogBrush.lbColor = GREEN;
            return 0;

        case ID_BRUSHCOLOUR_BLUE:
            CheckMenuItem(ghMainMenu, ID_BRUSHCOLOUR_BLUE, MF_CHECKED);
            CheckMenuItem(ghMainMenu, gCurrBrushColSel, MF_UNCHECKED);
            gCurrBrushColSel  = ID_BRUSHCOLOUR_BLUE;
            gLogBrush.lbColor = BLUE;
            return 0;

        //=====================================
        // Pen Styles
        //=====================================
        case ID_PENSTYLE_SOLID:
            CheckMenuItem(ghMainMenu, ID_PENSTYLE_SOLID, MF_CHECKED);
            CheckMenuItem(ghMainMenu, gCurrPenStyleSel, MF_UNCHECKED);
            gCurrPenStyleSel  = ID_PENSTYLE_SOLID;
            gLogPen.lopnStyle = PS_SOLID;
            return 0;

        case ID_PENSTYLE_DOTTED:
            CheckMenuItem(ghMainMenu, ID_PENSTYLE_DOTTED, MF_CHECKED);
            CheckMenuItem(ghMainMenu, gCurrPenStyleSel, MF_UNCHECKED);
            gCurrPenStyleSel = ID_PENSTYLE_DOTTED;
            gLogPen.lopnStyle = PS_DOT;
            return 0;

        case ID_PENSTYLE_DASHED:
            CheckMenuItem(ghMainMenu, ID_PENSTYLE_DASHED, MF_CHECKED);
            CheckMenuItem(ghMainMenu, gCurrPenStyleSel, MF_UNCHECKED);
            gCurrPenStyleSel  = ID_PENSTYLE_DASHED;
            gLogPen.lopnStyle = PS_DASH;
            return 0;

        //=====================================
        // Brush Styles
        //=====================================
        case ID_BRUSHSTYLE_SOLID:
            CheckMenuItem(ghMainMenu, ID_BRUSHSTYLE_SOLID, MF_CHECKED);
            CheckMenuItem(ghMainMenu, gCurrBrushStyleSel, MF_UNCHECKED);
            gCurrBrushStyleSel = ID_BRUSHSTYLE_SOLID;
            gLogBrush.lbStyle  = BS_SOLID;
            return 0;

        case ID_BRUSHSTYLE_NULL:
            CheckMenuItem(ghMainMenu, ID_BRUSHSTYLE_NULL, MF_CHECKED);
            CheckMenuItem(ghMainMenu, gCurrBrushStyleSel, MF_UNCHECKED);
            gCurrBrushStyleSel = ID_BRUSHSTYLE_NULL;
            gLogBrush.lbStyle  = BS_NULL;
            return 0;

        case ID_BRUSHSTYLE_DIAGONAL:
            CheckMenuItem(ghMainMenu, ID_BRUSHSTYLE_DIAGONAL, MF_CHECKED);
            CheckMenuItem(ghMainMenu, gCurrBrushStyleSel, MF_UNCHECKED);
            gCurrBrushStyleSel = ID_BRUSHSTYLE_DIAGONAL;
            gLogBrush.lbStyle  = BS_HATCHED;
            gLogBrush.lbHatch  = HS_CROSS;
            return 0;
        }

...
```

Comment: It's probably worth removing all non-menu message cases from your post for brevity, in addition to showing just how you attach the menu to the window. The code you've posted so far appears fine to me. It could be a problem with the way the menu is attached.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you check out [the documention of `WM_COMMAND`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647591%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you find that the command id is 16 bits.

2^16 = 65536, if memory serves.

Thus, a value of, say, 101000, is a bit too large.

---

By the way, it's generally a good idea to use the "message cracker" macros from `<windowsx.h>`, such as `HANDLE_WM_COMMAND`.

Also, for `WM_COMMAND`, be sure to check whether it's a child window notification or a real menu selection.

Comment: Minor nitpick: The ID's are in the range 0 to 65535 (65536 doesn't fit in 16 bits). This doesn't change the validity of the analysis, though.

Comment: @IInspectable: Mayor nitpick: Alf never said that 65536 was a valid ID. He said that the ID is 16 bits (true) and that 2^16=65536 (also true). This doesn't change the validity of your nitpick, though ;-).